# Aliasing a function definition - possible VS2013 bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to alias a function definition, as shown in the code below. There is a compiler error when the first function parameter is not a primitive type. I am assuming this is a compiler bug. Any thoughts? There is a workaround using the pre-processor, but this is not ideal.
The compile error is: `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void print1(int i, std::string s)
{
    std::cout << s << i << std::endl;
}

void print2(std::string s, int i)
{
    std::cout << s << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using FunDefn1 = void(int, std::string);   // OK
    //using FunDefn2 = void(std::string, int); // error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'

    // Workaround...
    #define FunDefn2 void(std::string, int)

    std::function<FunDefn1> p1 = print1;
    std::function<FunDefn2> p2 = print2;

    p2("Hello World!", 42);
    p1(42, "Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler error?

Comment: Works...as expected... with clang.

Comment: making it a `typedef` wont help either... definitely a bug in VS2013

Comment: It looks that way. I've logged a bug with MS Connect. Thanks.